# Who approves satellite launches, and what prevents anyone from just launching one from a legal standpoint?

Tags: artificial-satellite, regulatory

What regulatory process does one have to go through to get a satellite launch approved, and what, if anything, keeps satellites from different countries from colliding with each other?